# why my nuget package triggers dependency dll downgrade when install?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I have a nuget package that consumed by internal teams.
This is the dependency section in the nuspec file

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="5.2.9" />
  <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.2" />
  <dependency id="System.Runtime.Caching" version="4.5.0" />
  <dependency id="Polly" version="7.1.0" />
</dependencies>
```

When some teams installed my nuget package, they complained that some dlls were downgraded. For example:
[image]

and
[image]

Yes, the code does use newton. However, in my dependency section, I didn't hard code the exact version and from visual studio, it shows this and I think newton json version 13 should be bigger than 12.0.2?
[image]
Then for System.Memory, I didn't include that as a dependency, so how come its version got degraded?

Comment: Stupid me. I worked this out after sending the bunty. The problm is that I copied all these dependency dlls together in the package (e.g. version 12 newton.json dll is in the nuget package). Looks like visual studio or nuget will use that one over the one specified in the dependency section